How to read content of spl file(printer spool)
I have been trying to read a content of .spl file, or convert it to an image. Using PrintQueue and GetPrintJobInfoCollection I can read spl file info(or printing document info), like FullName or Submitter...
Can someone provide a simple example of parsing spl file, c#, or vb.net? or post some useful links?

Not sure what you mean by spl files. Did you see the description of the tag "spl" (just hover over it). It does not seem to apply to your question, or?

yeah, it's not spl I was thinking about, but will appear in google search, best I can do...

Don't misuse tags, please. If you refer to e.g. a "FutureSplash Animator" file, please make this explicit in the question.

The SPL file is just a compressed ZIP archive, you can open it with any tool (but not any archive manager can manipulate it, i.e., modify it). The content is mostly XML files that constitute the descriptors of the schemas, the PathGeometries that describes the rendering of the pages, the graphic files (bits and pieces) of elements in the page that cannot be rendered as a PathGeometry (or, elements where the source is actually a graphic object, e.g., when printing web pages), and the Metadata folder, which contains all the properties of the Document (still an XML file)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@zmrcic: See this recent answer of mine. Let me know if you have further questions.
